# How to display tooltip on hover event for all td values using directive in angularjs and jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jsfiddle

I want to display tooltip that contain the value of a TD value in a table

I want to do it using directive and jquery

Help me please, this is the jsfiddle link :

```
[blog]: http://jsfiddle.net/AJAAFRI/97u54/
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please include your code and errors in the question.

Comment: Question is valid. Needs rewording. OP is seeking how to make populate the title dynamically from the value of the node in AngularJS. Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/JvD2NWSGgTHp0FlQi6Eo?p=preview

Comment: One liner answer is attr.$set('title', elm.text());  in the directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Angular UI, http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.  It has a tooltip.

My 2 cents is to avoid intermixing too much jquery with angular.